# dna assembly with velvet; it runs velveth but doesn't regocinse velvetg

Tags: python

I have the above code to run velvet. I can run velveth with no problems but it is not recognising the parameter for velvetg. I have checked the documentation, and I cannot see anything different to what I have. when the programme reaches velveteg, **I get the following messege: [0.000000] unknown option: -ins_length 500.**

```
import glob, sys, os, subprocess

def velvet_project():
    print 'starting_velvet'
    #'this is the directory where I copied the two test files. H*, I realised this is a subdirectory *.gastq.gz, to process all the files with that extention' 
    folders = glob.glob('/home/my_name/fastqs_test/H*')
    #print folders
    for folder in folders:
        print folder
        #looking for fastqs in each folder
        fastqs=glob.glob(folder + '/*.fastq.gz')
        #print fastqs
        strain_id = os.path.basename(folder)
        output= '/home/my_name/velvet_results/' + strain_id + '_velvet'
        if os.path.exists(output):
            print 'velevet folder already exist'
        else:
            os.makedirs(output)
        #cmd is a command line within the programme#
        cmd=['velveth', output, '59', '-fastq.gz','shortPaired',fastqs[0],fastqs[1]]
        #print cmd
        my_file=subprocess.Popen(cmd)#I got this from the documentation.
        my_file.wait()
        print 'velveth has finished'
        cmd_2=['velvetg', output, '-ins_length 500', '-exp_cov auto', '-scaffoding no']
        print cmd_2
        my_file_2=subprocess.Popen(cmd_2)
        my_file_2.wait()
        print "velvet has finished :)"

print 'start'
velvet_project()
```

Comment: Please add more information in order to have more chances to have help. What is the problem? How it fails? Is it really a python problem or are you just giving wrong parameter to ``velvetg``?

Comment: Hi, I can run the velveth part with no probem. It creates the expected files but when I try to run velvetg it keeps telling me that -ins_length 500 is an unknown options. I removed the ' just in case that was the problem but it was even worst so put them back.

Comment: Can you call the failing command from command line?

Comment: I get the following message: [0.000000] unknown option: -ins_length 500

Comment: If you edit the question with the information, you have more chances that someone will reply

Comment: Thanks, I have just edited it as you suggested.